# ffmpeg is generating an out-of-sync audio/video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a `flv` video to `mp4` using `a264`, but the result video has a out of sync audio/video.  The audio seems ok but the video seems slow and therefore out of sync with the audio.

Here is the command I am running:

```
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i complaint.flv -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -copyts -strict experimental -fpre /opt/local/share/ffmpeg/libx264-lossless_slow.ffpreset -ab 44k -threads 0 -crf 23 complaint.mp4
```

And the output:

```
Desktop  /opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i complaint.flv -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -copyts -strict experimental -fpre /opt/local/share/ffmpeg/libx264-lossless_slow.ffpreset -ab 44k -threads 0 -crf 23 complaint.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.7.8, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 12 2012 21:12:26 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm
  libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
  libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
  libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
  libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
  libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
  libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[flv @ 0x7fe57a04ac00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from 'complaint.flv':
  Metadata:
    duration        : 7
    creationdate    : Thu Jan 12 23:47:24
    description     : Recorded using VideoRecording example.
  Duration: 00:00:06.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 288x288, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: nellymoser, 11025 Hz, mono, s16
File 'complaint.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[buffer @ 0x7fe579c32cc0] w:288 h:288 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_param:
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] using cpu capabilities: none!
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] profile High, level 4.2
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] 264 - core 118 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=2 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x33 me=umh subme=6 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'complaint.mp4':
  Metadata:
    duration        : 7
    creationdate    : Thu Jan 12 23:47:24
    description     : Recorded using VideoRecording example.
    encoder         : Lavf52.111.0
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 288x288, q=0-69, 200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 11025 Hz, mono, s16, 44 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 6557 fps=106 q=-1.0 Lsize=     685kB time=00:00:03.62 bitrate=1549.1kbits/s dup=6367 drop=0    
video:615kB audio:17kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 8.361360%
frame I:27    Avg QP:19.98  size:  8242
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] frame P:6530  Avg QP:30.71  size:    62
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] mb I  I16..4: 11.1% 79.3%  9.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.2%  0.0%  P16..4:  1.2%  0.2%  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] 8x8 transform intra:77.8% inter:64.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 75.3% 81.3% 33.3% inter: 0.5% 0.7% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 78%  9% 10%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 11% 32%  3%  4%  5%  2%  5%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 56%  7%  9%  3%  4%  7%  3%  7%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 15% 34%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] ref P L0: 80.5%  9.5% 10.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fe57a044600] kb/s:767.20
```

Is there something I'm missing to make sure the video and audio line up perfectly?

Comment: If you try 'ffmpeg -i complaint.flv complaint.mp4', does is it still out of sync? Is the original file out of sync when you play it in VLC?

Comment: That doesn't work for me, mainly because of the codecs that were used on the flv creating (different from h264)

Comment: From your answer I can't understand if 'ffmpeg -i complaint.flv complaint.mp4' produced output that's out of sync or not. That's the way you debug a problem, you try to isolate it. Is the original simply out of sync? If VLC plays it that way, then there's nothing you can do. Or is it a general problem with ffmpeg, or is it with the h264 codec specifically?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For those who may be trying this, I was better of recording flash in h264 right away, instead of using yuv420p for audio codec. That worked like a charm. Adding the flag `-async 1` also helped.

Update: Check out this bit from the ffmpeg documentation (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> **-async**: Audio sync method. "Stretches/squeezes" the audio stream to match the timestamps, the parameter is the maximum samples per second by which the audio is changed. -async 1 is a special case where only the start of the audio stream is corrected without any later correction. **This option has been deprecated. Use the aresample audio filter instead.**

You can read about the aresample filter here: http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/FilteringGuide

Comment: "in h264 right away, instead of using yuv420p for audio codec." ??? Do not understand. yuv420p is picture format, not video codec like h264, neither audio cedec. Then what did you do to get the sync?

Comment: Is this the equivalent? `aresample=async=1`

Comment: Not working for me. Webm -> mp4 still has video delay behind audio.

Comment: Thanks!  "-async 1" did it for me.

Comment: thanks, no idea how long it would have taken me to find this myself.